# Mysql wrong values in row return / latest records

Tags: mysql, group-by, record

I have a table like this:

```
VoerID   LogID  Status  Datum

1051        93  F   vr 08 okt 2004

1051    1037    A   di 19 okt 2004

1051    8955    A   di 18 jan 2005

1051    43972   A   wo 07 sep 2005

….  ….  ….. ……..

44444   10000000    V   someday 2013
```

So per `VoerID` I have several `LogID`’s. What I want to see is the latest `logID` per `VoerID`.
As an example I’ll only look at `VoerID` 1051.

Have made this so far:

```
select Voer.ID, Datum, Status, maxLogID 
from  (SELECT VoerID, Datum, Status, MAX(LogID) as maxLogID 
FROM DB.Log group by VoerID order by Status)t1 where VoerID = '1051'
```

When I execute this  the answer is

```
VoerID  LogID   Status  Datum

1051    43972   F   vr 08 okt 2004
```

So I get the latest LogId but not the corresponding Status and Date.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way to get the specified resultset (i.e. one row), assuming you have an appropriate index defined would be:

```
SELECT VoerID
     , Datum
     , Status
     , LogID
  FROM DB.Log
WHERE VoerID = '1051'
ORDER
   BY VoerID DESC
    , LogID DESC
LIMIT 1
```

To get the latest row for more than one VoerID (i.e. MAX(LogID) for each VoerID), you can use a JOIN operation against an inline view:

```
SELECT l.VoerID
     , l.Datum
     , l.Status
     , l.LogID
  FROM (
         SELECT k.VoerID
              , MAX(k.LogID) AS LogID
           FROM DB.Log k
          GROUP BY k.VoerID
       ) m
  JOIN DB.Log l
    ON l.VoerID = m.VoerID AND l.LogID = m.LogID
 ORDER BY l.VoerID ASC
```

For performance of both queries, you'll want an index defined `ON (VoerID, LogID)`

---

### Followup

**Q:** i would also like to count the nummber of VoerID per Status. is it possible to do tha t per end of the month? the could must then also take column timestamp logID into account...

**A:**  I didn't recognize that Datum column as a timestamp column.

To get a simple count of VoerID that have an occurrence of a row with a particular status:

```
SELECT l.Status
     , COUNT(DISTINCT l.VoerID)
  FROM DB.Log l
 GROUP BY l.Status
```

Your reference to "end of month" can be interpreted a couple of different ways.  Did you want a count of the VoerID where the latest LogID within a month is a particular status, or did you want the count to include any VoerID that had a particular status within a month.

It's not clear what resultset you are looking for, but this may give you an idea.

It's possible to add an expression which is a function on the timestamp column, to get the year and the month from the timestamp, e.g.

```
DATE_FORMAT(timestampcol,'%Y-%m') AS yyyymm
```

If you want return that as a date (if that's more convenient in your code than dealing with a string), e.g. like the first day of the month:

```
DATE_FORMAT(timestampcol,'%Y-%m-01') + INTERVAL 0 DAY AS yyyymm
```

(If that column is a string, and not a DATE, DATETIME, or TIMESTAMP column, there are functions available to convert it within the query.)

If you want to look at only the "latest" LogID for each VoerID, as in, the rows returned by the query above, something like this would work:

```
SELECT l.status
     , m.yyyymm
     , COUNT(DISTINCT m.VoerID) AS count_distinct_voerid
  FROM (
         SELECT k.VoerID
              , DATE_FORMAT(k.timestampcol,'%Y-%m-01') + INTERVAL 0 DAY AS yyyymm
              , MAX(k.LogID) AS LogID
           FROM DB.Log k
          GROUP
             BY k.VoerID
              , DATE_FORMAT(k.timestampcol,'%Y-%m-01') + INTERVAL 0 DAY
       ) m
  JOIN DB.Log l
    ON l.VoerID = m.VoerID AND l.LogID = m.LogID
 ORDER BY m.yyyymm DESC, l.status ASC
```

(Actually, the keyword DISTINCT could be omitted, it's redundant in this example, assuming that (LogID) is unique, or (VoerID,LogID) is unique.)

Comment: for this i've made an exemple for one VoerId, in fact i'm building towards an overview per status on a given date. So then i'll count the number of VoerID's with a certain Status.

Comment: @user2561151: use a JOIN operation against an inline view. For performance, you'll want an index `ON DB.Log (VoerID, LogID)`.

Comment: i would also like to count the nummber of VoerID per Status on a certain date (last day of the month). my table has a timestamp per LogID so the max LogID must take the timestamp into account?

Comment: @user2561151 This really needs to be a new question. Same goes for spencer7593

Comment: @spencer7593: thanks. I'll give you a little background info. I want to now how many voerID per status there are on each last day of a month. So bassicly if i want to see how many Status X and y and Z there where on 31-12-2012, i want to enter that month and year. the code must then exclude any LogID later than that date ( and time 23:59:59). In that way that i can view how many voerID had a certain status on a certain moment. preferably i get a table with years and monts as headers en status as rows and count as values...

Answer (score 1):

If you really wanted to do this with a dual select then the baest way to write this would be...

```
    SELECT v.VoerID,v.LogID,v.Status,v.Datum From tableName v 
    INNER JOIN (Select MAX(LogID) as lastID, VoerID FROM tableName GROUP BY VoerID) r 
    ON v.LogID=r.lastID ORDER BY v.VoerID DESC
```

I am not saying that is the fastest or best way of doing it, but the data that you offered and the query you had provided that is what it seems like you were trying to accomplish.  If you need any fine tuning please let me know!

Comment: thanks i've used a similar code that Spencer gave me... perhaps you could help my comment on that answer?

Comment: +1  This query returns the specified resultset, if we assume that LogID is unique. For performance, there will need to be an index with a leading column of LogID. Along with the assumption that LogID is unique, we're also likely assuming that it's the primary key, so a suitable index for the JOIN operation will be available.

Comment: I believe i understand what you are saying, you would like to add an index to this table correct and still have it return the same resultset?

Answer (score 0):

If LogID is always increasing, you could use this:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE (VoerID, LogID) IN (SELECT VoerID, MAX(LogID)
                          FROM yourtable
                          GROUP BY VoerID)
```

Subquery will return the maximum LogID for every VoerID, and the outer query will return all rows that have the maximum logid for every voerid.

Comment: That works ok, but takes a lot of time... anyway to optimize that?

Comment: @user2561151: you can optimize that by avoiding the `IN (subquery)`, and do a `JOIN (subquery)` instead and by having appropriate index defined `ON DB.Log (VoerID, LogID)`

Comment: @user2561151 i like this syntax more, because it's easier to read, but in MySQL joins are usually faster. An index on (VoerID, LogID) will probably help a lot.